# A Lemma Related to Oseledets' Theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, lyapunov-exponents

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability space, $T:X\to X$ measurable and preserves $\mu$, $A:X\to GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ measurable and $\log^+\Vert A\Vert$, $\log^+\Vert A^{-1}\Vert$ integrable. Define $A^1(x)=A(x)$,

$$A^n(x)=A(T^{n-1}x)A^{n-1}(x)=A(T^{n-1}x)\ldots A(x),\qquad n>1$$

and

$$\lambda(x,v)=\lim\limits_n\sup\frac{1}{n}\log\Vert A^n(x)v\Vert$$

The lemma (from Viana's *Lectures on Lyapunov Exponents*, Lemma 4.4.(iii), p.40) is:

> **Lemma:** $\lambda(x, v+v')=\max\{\lambda(x, v),\lambda(x, v')\}$ if $v+v'\ne 0$.

One side is easy using the fact that limsup and max can be changed in series, thus
\begin{align}
\max\{\lambda(x, v),\lambda(x, v')\}&=\lim\limits_n\sup\frac{1}{n}\log(\Vert A^n(x)v\Vert+\Vert A^n(x)v'\Vert)\\
&\geq \lim\limits_n\sup\frac{1}{n}\log(\Vert A^n(x)v+ A^n(x)v'\Vert)=\lambda(x, v+v')
\end{align}
The other side, I thought that maybe $\Vert{Av}\Vert+\Vert{Av'}\Vert\leq c(\Vert{Av}+{Av'}\Vert )$ if $v+v\ne 0, A\in GL_d(R)$, however it's not true as in dim 2 we can use diagonal matrix to make their angle approach $\pi$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I just use the fact that limsup and max can be changed for  series and log max{a,b} have constant bound difference with log (a+b), which can be eliminated by 1/n.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yeah, that is not a good notation for asking questions, but that's standard notation in texts though.

Comment: @saberlovelin Could you please add the source you are following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.

For a counterexample take say $A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\0&3\end{pmatrix}$. For $v=(1,1)$ and $v'=(0,-1)$ we have
$$
\lambda(x,v)=\lambda(x,v')=\log3\quad\text{but}\quad \lambda(x,v+v')=\log2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

In a set of [notes](https://www.mat.uc.cl/%7Ejairo.bochi/docs/oseledets.pdf) by J. Bochi, page pp. 5, the author states a similar statement to that of the OP's but  with a slightly different assumption:

> \begin{align}
> \lambda(x;v+v')\leq\max\{\lambda(x;v),\lambda(x,v')\}\tag{0}\label{zero}
> \end{align}
> with equality if $\lambda(x;v)\neq\lambda(x;v')$.

This statement and many others there are left as exercise. Here is proof

The OP has already established that
\begin{align}
\lambda(x;u+v)\leq\max(\lambda(x;u),\lambda(x;v))\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}

Notice that $\lambda(x;\alpha v)=\lambda(x;v)$ for all scalar $\alpha\neq0$ and vector $v\neq0$.

Suppose $\lambda(x;u)\neq\lambda(x;v)$ and w.l.g., $\lambda(x;v)<\lambda(x,u)$ so that $\max(\lambda(x;u),\lambda(x;v))=\lambda(x;u)$.
Applying \eqref{one} yields
$$\lambda(x;v+u)\leq\lambda(x;u)=\lambda(x;u+v-v)\leq\max\{\lambda(x;u+v),\lambda(x;v)\}$$
If $\lambda(x;u+v)\leq\lambda(x;v)$, then $\lambda(x;u)\leq \lambda(x;v)$ which leads to a contradiction. Therefore
$\lambda(x;u+v)> \lambda(x;v)$ and so
\begin{align}
\lambda(x;u+v)=\lambda(x;u)=\max\{\lambda(x;v),\lambda(x;u)\}
\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}

This case is weaker than what the OP states in the posting ( $u+v\neq0$ ).  The best I have obtain  in that direction is
\begin{align}
\lambda(x;u+v)&\leq \max\{\lambda(x,u),\lambda(x,v)\}\\
&=\limsup_n\frac1n\log\big(\sqrt{\|A^n(x)u\|^2+\|A^n(x)v\|^2}\big)\\
&=\limsup_n\frac1n\log\Big(\sqrt{\frac{\|A^n(x)(u+v)\|^2+\|A^n(x)(u-v)\|^2}{2}}\Big)\\
&=\limsup_n\frac{1}{2n}\log\big(\|A^n(x)(u+v)\|^2+\|A^n(x)(u-v)\|^2\big)\\
&=\max\big\{\lambda(x;u+v),\lambda(x,u-v)\big\}
\end{align}
which follows from the identity
\begin{align}
\limsup_n\frac1n\log(a_n+b_n)&=\max\big\{\limsup_n\frac1n\log(a_n),\limsup_n\frac1n\log(b_n)\big\}\\
&=\limsup_n\frac1n\log\big(\sqrt{a^2_n+b^2_n}\big)
\end{align}
for sequences $a_n,b_n>0$.

**Edit:** As user John B has shown, the statement of the problem as it appears in M. Viana's textbook does not hold in general when $\lambda(x,u)=\lambda(x,v)$.